# Number of pairs $(A, B)$ such that $A \subseteq B$ and $B \subseteq \{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, binomial-coefficients

I need to determine the number of pairs $(A,B)$ of sets such that $A \subseteq B$ and $B \subseteq \{1,2,\ldots,n\}$

My solution:

How $A \subseteq B$ and $B \subseteq \{1,2,\ldots,n\}$, we have:

$$A :=  B := \sum_{i = 0}^{n} \left(\begin{array}{c} n \\ i \end{array} \right)$$

in this way, we have that the number of pairs $(A,B)$ of sets are:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} \left( \begin{array}{c} n \\ i \end{array}\right) + \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} \left( \begin{array}{c} n \\ i \end{array}\right)}{2} \cdot \left( \begin{array}{c} n \\ 0 \end{array}\right) + \left( \begin{array}{c} n \\ 0 \end{array}\right) \\ 2^n + 2^{n-1} + 1 $$

Here is a little example.

Suppose $n = 2$ 
Then $A \subseteq B$ and $B \subseteq \{1,2\}$. With this, we have:

$$(A, B) = (\emptyset,\emptyset), (\emptyset,{1}), (\emptyset,{2}), (\emptyset, {1,2}), ({1}, {1}), ({1}, {1,2}), ({1,2}, {1,2})$$

Comment: Have you considers examples for small $n$?  Perhaps a useful pattern will suggest itself.  In any case, you need to have explicit examples so you can test any result you arrive at.

Comment: I should note:  the problem statement doesn't say anything about any set being empty or non-empty, though you appear to introduce conditions of that form in your calculation.  I'd have said $A=B=\emptyset$ was a perfectly good example of what is called for, for any $n$.

Comment: Clarification needed : Are A, B proper or improper subsets?

Comment: @lulu, but I have a question. the statement don't ensure that A $\subseteq$ B and B $\subseteq \left\{1,2,...,n\right\}$, it ensures that A $\subset$ B and B $\subset \left\{ 1,2,...,n\right\}$. Why I don't suppose that A and B can't be empty sets?

Comment: @cosmo5, I understood it as proper subsets

Comment: Why introduce new conditions?  The problem just says "subsets" with no further qualifications.  I'd say $\emptyset\subseteq \emptyset\subseteq \{1, \cdots, n\}$ was a perfectly good instance.  As would $\{1, \cdots, n\}\subseteq \{1, \cdots, n\}\subseteq \{1, \cdots, n\}$. But it's your problem.  If you want to add new conditions, go ahead.  Just be very clear as to what conditions you are adding.

Comment: More importantly;  Examples are the key.  If you work a couple of examples, I think the pattern will be obvious to you.

Comment: @lulu Ah ok. I made a little example here, and I understood better. I'm sorry if I stress you.

Comment: What results did you get for your examples?  I suggest adding them to your post, so people can be clear what assumptions you are making.

Comment: As for the standard exercise similar to this where we do allow for improper subsets... as a hint, for each element $i$ of $\{1,2,3,\dots,n\}$ for $A\subseteq B\subseteq \{1,2,\dots,n\}$ to be true you will have exactly one of the following three conditions be true: $i$ is not an element of either $A$ nor $B$, $i$ is not an element of $A$ but is an element of $B$, or $i$ is an element of both $A$ and $B$.

Comment: @lulu, pls, Is this correct?

Comment: No.  You need to count pairs, not individual subsets.  For $n=1$ I see three pairs, namely $(A,B)=(\emptyset, \emptyset), (\emptyset, \{1\}), (\{1\}, \{1\})$.  Now try $n=2$.  I don't think you'll want to write out $n=4$ by hand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We use $[n]$ to denote the set of natural numbers $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$.

> We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{{(A,B)}\atop{A\subseteq B\subseteq[n]}}1}
> &=\sum_{B\subseteq [n]}\sum_{A\subseteq B}1\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^n\sum_{{B\subseteq [n]}\atop{|B|=j}}\sum_{k=0}^j\sum_{{A\subseteq B}\atop{|A|=k}}1\tag{1}\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^n\binom{n}{j}\sum_{k=0}^j\binom{j}{k}\tag{2}\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^n\binom{n}{j}2^j\tag{3}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=3^n}\tag{4}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we rearrange the sum according to terms with increasing size of subsets $A$ and $B$.
- In (2) we use the fact that the number of subsets of size $q$ of a finite set $X$ is $\binom{|X|}{q}$.
- In (3) and (4) we apply the binomial theorem.

> **Example: $n=2$**
>
> We have the following $3^2=9$ pairs $(A,B)$ when considering $[2]=\{1,2\}$:
>
> \begin{align*}
> &(\emptyset,\emptyset),\\
> &(\emptyset,\{1\}),\,(\{1\},\{1\}),\\
> &(\emptyset,\{2\}),\,(\{2\},\{2\}),\\
> &(\emptyset,\{1,2\})\,(\{1\},\{1,2\}),\,(\{2\},\{1,2\}),\,(\{1,2\},\{1,2\})
> \end{align*}

Comment: thank you @Markus Scheuer, I believe I can understand now

Comment: @MatheusSousa: You're welcome! Good to see the answer is helpful. :-)

Answer (score 2):

To each of the elements of $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}=[n]$, we assign a $a,b$ or $c$, independently. We have $3^n$ ways to do this.

For each assignment we make a pair $(A,B)$ as follows: if $i \to a$ we put $i$ in $A$ and also in $B$, if $i \to b$ we put $i$ in $B$ and if $i \to c$ we put it in neither $A$ nor $B$. Then $(A,B)$ is a good pair and to each such pair there is also a unique such assignment as above (based on the partition $A$,$B \setminus A$, $[n]\setminus (A \cup B)$, etc. So there are also $3^n$ such pairs.

Answer (score 0):

First we count the possibilities for $B$.  So if $B$ has $k$ elements, $0 \leq k \leq n$, then there are ${n \choose k}$ possibilities. For each of these possibilities for $B$, there are
$$ \sum_{i=0}^{{n \choose k}} {{n \choose k} \choose i} $$
possibilities for $A$. So to conclude, if $B$ has $k$ elements, then there are
$$ {n \choose k} \cdot \sum_{i=0}^{{n \choose k}} {{n \choose k} \choose i} $$
possible pairs of sets $(A,B)$.

Since we can choose any $0 \leq k \leq n$, sum over all values of $k$:
$$ \sum_{k=0}^{n} \left( {n \choose k} \cdot \sum_{i=0}^{{n \choose k}} {{n \choose k} \choose i} \right)$$